# How can I disable auto refresh in GitAhead

Tags: gitahead

I need to disable auto refresh in GitAhead because sometimes when I look on changes made in older commit, GitAhead automatically refreshes and scrolls to uncommitted files. So the main problem is not actually the refresh itself but the scroll to top, so disabling this would be preferable but I assumed it is unlikely I would be able to disable dis feature.

I am using the latest version of GitAhead ( 2.6.1. )  with no additional plugins on Ubuntu 19.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an option to disable automatic refresh when the working directory changes. Please add an issue to the issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem then I realised that git is tracking wrapper/native/
daemon/ caches/ directories which is causing it to refresh again and again. Putting these directories in `.gitinore` fixed the issue.

i.e add:

```
wrapper/
native/
daemon/
caches/
```